# How do I write aeson ToJSON instances for types with kind (* -> *) -> *

Tags: haskell, aeson

## Motivation

I have a type, `MyType`, which is parametrised by a functor, `f`.

I want to use `MyType Identity` to represent "my view" of the data, and `MyType Maybe` to represent the type of *updates* to the data.

## Problem

Is it possible to write an aeson `ToJSON` instance for `MyType`? I tried to use the `ToJSON` class, but I get an error (see bottom of post).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module Main where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

data MyType f = MyType
  { age  :: f Int
  , name :: f String
  } deriving(Generic)

instance ToJSON1 f => ToJSON (MyType f)

main :: IO ()
main = print . encode $ MyType (Just 1) (Just "hi")
```

How can I get a ToJSON instance for `MyType f`, for an arbitrary `f`?

## Compilation error

```
Main.hs:12:10: error:
    • Could not deduce (ToJSON (f String))
        arising from a use of ‘aeson-1.2.4.0:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.$dmtoJSON’
      from the context: ToJSON1 f
        bound by the instance declaration
        at Main.hs:12:10-39
    • In the expression:
        aeson-1.2.4.0:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.$dmtoJSON @MyType f
      In an equation for ‘toJSON’:
          toJSON = aeson-1.2.4.0:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.$dmtoJSON @MyType f
      In the instance declaration for ‘ToJSON (MyType f)’
   |
12 | instance ToJSON1 f => ToJSON (MyType f)
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Looks like you need to know `forall a. ToJSON a => ToJSON (f a)`.  Perhaps a [`Lifting ToJSON f`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10/docs/Data-Constraint-Lifting.html) constraint will fit the bill?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Constraint - could you point me at some reading material, or show me how adding that constraint looks in syntax? (or both!)

Comment: @luqui: Couldn’t you also use `QuantifiedConstraints` to express that directly in GHC 8.6?

Comment: @JonPurdy maybe? Haven't played with them yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using my idea in the comment of exploiting the [`Lifting`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10/docs/Data-Constraint-Lifting.html) class, and after some tinkering I arrived at this

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric
           , FlexibleContexts   
           , MultiParamTypeClasses
           , ScopedTypeVariables
           , TypeApplications
           , UndecidableInstances 
           #-}
module Main where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Lifting

data MyType f = MyType
  { age  :: f Int
  , name :: f String
  } deriving(Generic)

instance (Lifting ToJSON f) => ToJSON (MyType f) where
    toJSON mt
        | Sub Dict <- lifting @ToJSON @f @Int
        , Sub Dict <- lifting @ToJSON @f @String
            = genericToJSON defaultOptions mt

instance Lifting ToJSON Maybe where
    lifting = Sub Dict

main :: IO ()
main = print . encode $ MyType (Just 1) (Just "hi")
```

Notes:

- [`Dict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Dict) converts back and forth between constraints (such as `ToJSON Int`) and values.  [`Sub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t::-45-) is just the constructor for constraint entailment.
- `lifting @ToJSON @f @Int` is [type application syntax](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications).
- I used `genericToJSON defaultOptions` by looking up the [default implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.0.0/docs/src/Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.html#ToJSON) for `toJSON`.  We just needed to manually bring some instances into scope with `lifting` first.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This looks pretty spot on - I'll have to do some reading though! Thanks.